# how to remove excess data in javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I have some HTML form which looks like this:

```html
<input type='checkbox'  name='lecture'  value='1' >
<input type='checkbox'  name='lecture'  value='2' >
<input type='checkbox'  name='lecture'  value='3' >
<input type='checkbox'  name='lecture'  value='4' >
```

I also have some jQuery code that adds all checked values to an array and this array goes to the input value:

```js
$('#separate_course_list').on("change", ":checkbox", function() {
  var values = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get(); // ["1", "2", "4"]
  $("input[name='comment']").val(values); //this input saves array
});
```

In the `console.log`, I have this (lets pretend that I check first checkbox, then third, then second):

```
["1", "815643", "753327", "752023"] // checked first checkbox
["1", "3", "815643", "753327", "752023"]//checked third checkbox
["1", "3", "2", "815643", "753327", "752023"]// checked second checkbox
```

The `slice(-1,3)` is not working.

Comment: So your only wanting the values associated with those checkboxes?  the one with name lecture?  Why not map on those rather than all checkboxes page wide?  It seems like your trying to solve a self imposed problem instead of trying to not cause the problem in the first place.

Comment: But from where come `"815643", "753327", "752023"` ???  I'm not sure to understand what is the question?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is considering all the checkboxes on the page which are checked so the extra values are of some other checkboxes, instead use `.map` on `input:checkbox:checked[name="lecture"]`

```
$('#separate_course_list').on("change", ":checkbox", function () {

        var values = $('input:checkbox:checked[name="lecture"]').map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get(); // ["1", "2", "4"]

        $("input[name='comment']").val(values); //this input saves array

});
```

Comment: Op already commented `// ["1", "2", "4"]` so i guess this was already expected/returned result. I could be wrong because this is completly unclear what is asked here, imho

Comment: thank you very much. now it works!
but it is so strange that i don't haave extra checkboxes excerpt these ones.
TY, you saved my nerves

Comment: So for the future, your comment about what the map was returning was inaccurate.  Make sure to provide accurate, and complete, descriptions of your problems when you post, otherwise it is difficult for us to identify the problem to be able to hel you resolve it.

Comment: oh i see. i have some problems with explaining. my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Why you slice start from -1 ?

first parameters of the slice method is the first index you want to remove, the second is the number of data you want to delete

```
var array = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"];
array.splice(1,3);
```

output should be :

`Orange,Lemon`

Source : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

Comment: So you just copied stuff from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp), which is more than defamed, (see http://w3fools.com), and how does that even make an answer? Kindly edit your answer to match with the question's requirements.

Comment: He can think by himslef, giving the answer is not constructive... moreover for an easyest think like a split... and comparing to some people I put my sources if I use existing example...

Comment: Okay nice. I don't know even who voted you up for the answer, but good luck. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, your syntax is **wrong**. Sorry to say that, the syntax of `slice` is:

```
arr.slice([begin[, end]])
```

And when you give:

```
slice(-1, 3)
```

The array cannot have a value of `-1` as the beginning. So you must be looking for:

```
slice(3, -1)
```

Which starts from index `3` and ends before the last one, leaving the last one, if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to determine which check box has been checked last, you can use the code snippet below. In case you wanted all checked checkboxes you can just use `slice(0,3)`.

```js
a= ["1", "815643", "753327", "752023"] // checked first checkbox
b = ["1", "3", "815643", "753327", "752023"] // checked third checkbox
c = ["1", "3", "2", "815643", "753327", "752023"]// checked second checkbox

function IsCheckBox(value) {
  return value < 4;
}

document.write("Checked checkbox " + a.slice(0,3).filter(IsCheckBox).slice(-1)[0] +'<br>')

document.write("Checked checkbox " + b.slice(0,3).filter(IsCheckBox).slice(-1)[0] +'<br>')

document.write("Checked checkbox " + c.slice(0,3).filter(IsCheckBox).slice(-1)[0] +'<br>')


//Alternatively if you want all checked checkboxed this will suffice

document.write("Checked checkboxes " + c.slice(0,3))
```